# how to use grid in column?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am developing a flutter app and I need to use grid in the column, but without using a container or sized box,

I keep getting this error

```
════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderRepaintBoundary#b8f58 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1930 pos 12: 'hasSize'

The relevant error-causing widget was
TabBarView
lib\screens\home_screen.dart:13
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderRepaintBoundary#0725a NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1930 pos 12: 'hasSize'

The relevant error-causing widget was
TabBarView
lib\screens\home_screen.dart:13
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════
'package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_multi_box_adaptor.dart': Failed assertion: line 544 pos 12: 'child.hasSize': is not true.
```

any idea???

note: I need to do it without a container or sized box.

That's my grid view

```
class ProductsGrid extends StatelessWidget {
  const ProductsGrid({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final productsData = Provider.of<Products>(context).products;
    return GridView.builder(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
      itemCount: productsData.length,
      itemBuilder: (ctx, i) => ProductItem(),
      gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
        crossAxisCount: 2,
        childAspectRatio: 3 / 3,
        crossAxisSpacing: 1,
        mainAxisSpacing: 1,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and that's my column

```
Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
            child: ImageSlideshow(
              width: double.infinity,
              height: 150,
              initialPage: 0,
              indicatorColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
              indicatorBackgroundColor: Colors.grey,
              onPageChanged: (value) {
                debugPrint('Page changed: $value');
              },
              autoPlayInterval: 0,
              isLoop: false,
              children: [
                Image.asset(
                  'assets/shopping_online.jpg',
                  fit: BoxFit.fill,
                ),
                Image.asset(
                  'assets/shopping_online.jpg',
                  fit: BoxFit.fill,
                ),
                Image.asset(
                  'assets/shopping_online.jpg',
                  fit: BoxFit.fill,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Divider(),
          Expanded(
            child: ProductsGrid(),
          )
        ],
      )
```

any idea???

note: I need to do it without a container or sized box.

Comment: You need to use an Expanded or Flexible box in order to make it work, that's the only way if you don't want to use a container (with size) or sizedbox.

Comment: I keep getting the same error when using the expanded or flexible widget

Comment: then you need to post your code... is impossible to guess without it.

Comment: I added my gridView builder and column, can you please check

Comment: mr.Mariano, can you please check my code and see what is wrong?

Comment: we need to know what's wrapping your main Column as the logic is correct so far. Try to comment out the "Padding" with the "ImageSlideshow" one for testing. Also, try to remove the Divider for now... you're not even setting a height for that element.

Comment: commented padding and removed divider, still the same issue

Comment: then something is wrong with the widget on top of the column. That code, standalone works as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what you missed --> **shrinkWrap: true,**

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 50),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: GridView.builder(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                itemCount: 8,
                itemBuilder: (context, i) => Container(
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  height: 50,
                  width: 50,
                ),
                gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                  crossAxisCount: 2,
                  childAspectRatio: 1,
                  crossAxisSpacing: 20,
                  mainAxisSpacing: 20,
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

[image]

Also you will need this --> **physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),**

I am not going to explain this. Wrap your Column with SingleChildScrollView and see what happens.

Comment: nope, it didn't work either. still getting the same error

Comment: remove ImageSlideshow widget from the column and add shrinkWrap: true to your grid view and check.

Comment: image slide show is the reason I am using column, plus i removed it for trying and still the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work out:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: GridView.builder(
              gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                crossAxisCount: //array length,
              ),
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => 
               YourWidget(),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: I put it in expanded widget and I keep getting the same error.

Comment: I double checked the code and its running perfectly. Try the layout once and let me know if you are facing the same issues.

Comment: I am looking at it.

Comment: I put the gridview builder in the expanded as it should be, I don't know why I am getting the same error

Comment: The width that you have specified will take the full width but you want it to display in the form of grids. Remove the width or give a finite width and check.

Comment: where, exactly?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236540/discussion-between-mohamad-jabaly-and-arijeet).

Answer (score 0):

**Please note that the title of the question does not match properly with the error. But try this.**

Grid view should be like this

```
class ProductsGrid extends StatelessWidget {
  const ProductsGrid({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final productsData = Provider.of<Products>(context).products;
    return GridView.builder(
      shrinkWrap: true,
      physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
      itemCount: productsData.length,
      itemBuilder: (ctx, i) => ProductItem(),
      gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
        crossAxisCount: 2,
        childAspectRatio: 3 / 3,
        crossAxisSpacing: 1,
        mainAxisSpacing: 1,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Column should be like this

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30, vertical: 50),
          child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
            child: ImageSlideshow(
              width: double.infinity,
              height: 150,
              initialPage: 0,
              indicatorColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
              indicatorBackgroundColor: Colors.grey,
              onPageChanged: (value) {
                debugPrint('Page changed: $value');
              },
              autoPlayInterval: 0,
              isLoop: false,
              children: [
                Image.asset(
                  'assets/shopping_online.jpg',
                  fit: BoxFit.fill,
                ),
                Image.asset(
                  'assets/shopping_online.jpg',
                  fit: BoxFit.fill,
                ),
                Image.asset(
                  'assets/shopping_online.jpg',
                  fit: BoxFit.fill,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Divider(),
          ProductsGrid(),
        ],
      )
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Don't do that. That's the worst practice you can do. Both, ListView and GridView recycle elements out of the screen to save on memory and performance... when you put those inside a SingleChildScrollView you're literally disabling the ListView/GridView functionality, loading ALL the values in memory having a terrible performance and memory consumption

Comment: @MarianoZorrilla Thanks for the point. I never really notice that. I'll test that scenario. But is there any other workaround to do that?

Comment: That's what Expended is all about. Takes the available space from a Column and draws there... is like a sizedbox that expands without the need of knowing the actual available size. Works with Columns and Rows. If you need something more powerful, use a CustomScrollView with Slivers and you'll be fine.